# how to infer that a class can be instantiated in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

sometime we need template method to build abstract relationship about something similar，for example:

```
abstract class Animal {
  constructor(public head: string, public leg: string, public hand: string) {}
}

class Bird extends Animal {}

class Human extends Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {}

// more...
```

correspondingly, we also need some functions to create instance of Class above:

```
function createBird(head: string, leg: string, hand: string) {
  return new Bird(head, leg, hand)
}

function createHuman(head: string, leg: string, hand: string) {
  return new Human(head, leg, hand)
}

function createCat(head: string, leg: string, hand: string) {
  return new Cat(head, leg, hand)
}
```

But I think this is not elegant enough because there is a lot of repetitive content inside. Even worse, if we want to change the abtract Class 'Animal':

```
abstract class Animal {
  constructor(public head: string, public leg: string, public hand: string, public foot:string) {}
}
```

I add a param in constructor, next, I must modify every function that creates subclass instances, it's so bad.
my solution is as follows:

```
function createClass<T extends typeof Animal>(C: T, head: string, leg: string, hand: string) {
  return new C(head, leg, hand)
}

const bird = createClass(Bird, '', '', '')

const human = createClass(Human, '', '', '')

const cat = createClass(Cat, '', '', '')
```

But it will prompt for type error that the abstract Class cannot be instantiated.
I don't know how to derive the correct type, so I ask for help

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mxxK8m) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: If I want to make this function more versatile,  like this [playground](https://aad.tw/ee3m) . how can I solve the type error

Comment: I don't see how requiring an extra argument makes the function more "versatile", instead it's making it more restrictive.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/w29jYW) to clear up that error.  If that doesn't help or you have more questions about it, please open a new post for it.  Followup questions don't belong in comments sections and such comments might get deleted as off-topic.

Comment: yes, I truly want to make this function more restrictive,  you answer solve this problem. I probably know where my mistake is, But I still look forward to your wonderful answer. this is [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76478902/how-to-derive-the-correct-type-for-creating-subclass-instance-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general version of `createClass` won't care about `Animal` or a particular list of constructor argument types at all. Instead, it will accept any concrete constructor object and the list of arguments expected by that constructor, and returns the created instance:

```
function createClass<A extends any[], T extends object>(
    C: new (...a: A) => T, ...args: A
) {
    return new C(...args)
}
```

That function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `A`, the list of arguments, and `T`, the instance type.  The `C` parameter has a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) `new (...a: A) => T`, meaning if you `new` it with an argument list of type `A`, you'll get a `T` out.

This will work with your examples:

```
class Bird extends Animal { }
const bird = createClass(Bird, '', '', '');
class Human extends Animal { }
const human = createClass(Human, '', '', '');
class Cat extends Animal { }
const cat = createClass(Cat, '', '', '');
```

as well as any other constructor you want to use:

```
const date = createClass(Date, 1686749440441);
// const date: Date
console.log(date.getFullYear()) // 2023
```

Therefore it will automatically adapt to any changes in the `Animal` constructor parameter types, or if any subclass of `Animal` has a different list of constructor parameter types.

---

If you really want to restrict the `C` input to `Animal` constructors, to prevent `createClass(Date, 1686749440441);`, you could do so by [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T`:

```
function createClass<A extends any[], T extends Animal>( // <-- constrained more
    C: new (...a: A) => T, ...args: A
) {
    return new C(...args)
}

const bird = createClass(Bird, '', '', ''); // okay
const human = createClass(Human, '', '', ''); // okay
const cat = createClass(Cat, '', '', ''); // okay

const date = createClass(Date, 1686749440441); // error!
//   ------------------> ~~~~
// Type 'Date' is missing the following properties from type 'Animal': ...
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=24#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAWACgFqkB7bSKAV3lqgAoAHJkZXWBAAsApsAAmALgSNc2AOYAaBN178EyYXKkz5SlXwGDg2SdOiy5ASlIIAvpXsVKAMybZ4uekiiiIwgMKo6AA8mAjCAB5+JhjGAJ4A2gC6SgAq4VHCMQi0IABWwvAAfOyUNAj+UtjCAO4I7AB0TcBSmNYAvEUIqUpNDcBQcmCtlNbkVDQ+EExQ2AjVdf6NzYNglg6UlChoGABCuFBiGdFiGDgERDaOsPSQCCAHR+3evgFBYOz7h0oA5D+--wQf0sAG4tu8EAAJJiEOaRE5nPCEYgkOxbW6IQQw4wIZ6wHzAPyBHbsaGwgEUoE-UHgnYVQnHLKnLBIy6o64YpAMvEEonvdj+QmUv4AmlOcU3BiIMSE4S4l6y4nodgAEVlSgAjAA2AAcWoA7AAWACchsNAAYzRqxQB6G10KUIGV+KRqvzohi0DQNZC0OTsZ3CBpyYQQABiTGQyAAmqIOJZQQg7QgAEzmlMAZk24so2GA+GEYE4cDl-gxMFkwiO4zKNFc7ggnjm+NeSrAoUZ2XiyTSneZ52RJST9toAGtgHFa+VqJV5rV6n0WlgOl0eghF6sRhNqGMp9OpjM5gsKst+qt1tu0eLypK7g9DvKW4r+V8xMLAcCwZfb5jsXMea2-JksY76il+N6crA3IKnyJKChAoFUmKe4-k6sqPrybwkm6wiarqBommalqGta4E0MmwhQFAbAAIQIAAtIxTHMUxXQAH4cWxe7JqkcScHKPw4T8CC4Bg+CiWAFgIBAIgIM4Xq+jUUmcNR-FQI2hZydR+DSXxAkDkQPxSH02amRQthAA)