# In TypeScript, does Class sometimes not solve the problem of parameter modification or extension well

Tags: typescript

Through the example of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76470093/how-to-infer-that-a-class-can-be-instantiated-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment134835684_76470093) , I feel that the 'Class' is struggling with parameter extension issues. If I use functions from the beginning:

```
type IAnimalParams = [string, string, string]

function createAnimal(...args: IAnimalParams) {
    // do somthing about animal
    return {
        head:args[0],
        leg:args[1],
        hand: args[2]
    }
}

function createHuman(...args: IAnimalParams) {
    const animal = createAnimal(...args)
    // do something about human
    return {
        ...animal,
        // other attributes about human
    }
}

function createBird(...args: IAnimalParams) {
    const animal = createAnimal(...args)
    // do something about bird
    return {
        ...animal,
        // other attributes about bird
    }
}
```

In this case, I use function and the 'mixins', now I don't need the function 'createClass', I just need to compose 'createAnimal' with future changes. if I want to change the 'Animal', I also don't need to modify anything about Human or Bird. Does this mean that 'Class' is not a better solution in this case ? or do I have not found the correct way to use it.
this is [playground](https://aad.tw/bx6c)